# Remove Prices from WooCommerce in Catalog Page only

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to remove the prices from my products in WooCommerce in the catalog page only. The prices will remain in the individual page and the checkout. Unfortunately, I am not using a child theme, and WooCommerce is bundled with the theme.

Comment: You could really do with posting some code for people to have a look at, can you try and post the catalogue page template or the relevant section?

Comment: Or at least the theme

Comment: It's a theme called "The Galaxy" by WPLabs (they don't help with WooThemes) like most themes. What code should I post that would help ?

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/61398/hide-price-title-in-store-thumbnail-dispay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding

```
.price.grid-only 
{
    display: none !important;
}
```

to the css file. It should only hide the price on the shop page, but not the individual pages.

Answer (score 5):

You can remove the price hook from the woocommerce loop.

Add below code to your **theme - functions.php** file

```
remove_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_price',10);
```

Comment: Construction page is still there.

Comment: Are you using an customized shop page for this or default woocommerce shop page?
Can you post the code which you are using to display the products **( the product loop )**. Maybe then I can tell how exactly you can fix that.